# using div to toggle different text in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html

Here is the code i have:

```
<a class="clickMe">Text 1</a>
<br />
<div class="sri"> - This text will be toggled</div>

<a class="clickMe">Text 2</a>
<br />
<div class="sri"> - This text will be toggled 2</div>
```

and the Jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('a.clickMe').click(function () {
        // find first of following DIV siblings
        // with class "textBox" and toggle it
        $(this).nextAll('div.sri:first').toggle();
    });
});
```

now it's working fine by displaying 'This text will be toggled' and by hiding 'This text will be toggled 2' when Text1 is clicked, but i want it work in the oppsite way, that is, 
it should hide 'This text will be toggled' and display 'This text will be toggled 2' when Text1 is clicked.
Please help me to fix this.

Comment: no dear i dont want to hide it...it should be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why need extra classes this will solve your question

```
    $('a.clickMe').click(function () {
        // find first of following DIV siblings
        // with class "textBox" and toggle it
$(this).nextAll('div.sri:first').show();        
$('div.sri:visible').not($(this).nextAll('div.sri:first')).toggle();

    });​
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LTYa2/5/)

Comment: hi rahul as i have mentioned in a previous comment ..it works fine when we click on 'text2' for the first time by displaying 'This text will be toggled 2' and when you click on 'text2' immediatley for the second time it displays both  'This text will be toggled 2' and 'This text will be toggled '...ideally it should display only 'This text will be toggled 2' please help me to fix

Comment: Thanks alot for showing interest in solving this problem dear... but now it caused an other issues ..when we click on text2 for the second time yes  it works fine by not displaying ' 'This text will be toggled' but immediatlt if we click on 'text1' it should display 'This text will be toggled' but it is hiding both now...:(...

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$(function () {
$('a.clickMe').click(function () {
    // find first of following DIV siblings
    // with class "textBox" and toggle it
       $('div.sri').eq(1).toggle();
});
});
```

Comment: sorry to mention in a question  Utkarshyour code is working fine,, by hiding 'This text will be toggled 2' when Text 1 is clicked .... but in the same way it should hide 'This text will be toggled' when Text 2 is clicked......please help me wth that

Comment: i may also have to use more 'texts' like text1,text2,text3,text4 and the respective divs should be shown or hidden... please help me wth that

Comment: if you want to toggle first div then use $('div.sri').eq(0).toggle(); you have to set the visibilty of these divs

Comment: if you are going to have more than 2 div then you should use gt() and lt() menthod of jquery , read more from http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Answer (score 0):

try this :

html :

```
<a class="clickMe a1">Text 1</a>
<br />
<div class="a2"> - This text will be toggled</div>

<a class="clickMe a2">Text 2</a>
<br />
<div class="a1"> - This text will be toggled 2</div>
```

js :

```
$(function () {
$('a.clickMe').click(function () {

    var class1 = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
    $("div." + class1).toggle();
});
});
```

Comment: what is the need of extra classes when you can do it without it

Comment: @rahul when you have more than two pair of <a> &<div> then you need extra class.

Comment: one more problem anil ...code is working fine "when you click on 'text1' it hides 'This text will be toggled 2' same way when we click on text2 it hides 'This text will be toggled' ,,,but again if i click on text2 ideally there should be no changes but it is displaying both 'This text will be toggled' and 'This text will be toggled 2' ,,,same issues with rahul's code,,, please help me to fix this...

Comment: @AnilBharadia i have add an answer please look at that it will work for as many <a> and <div> user want